# Different outcome after applying ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following class:

```
public class Score
{
    private static readonly Guid _relationId = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RelationId { get { return _relationId; } }

    public Score()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

The following function:

```
public IEnumerable<Score> GetScores()
{
    yield return new Score();
    yield return new Score();
    yield return new Score();
}
```

Why is it that the following function returns **1**:

```
public int Execute()
{
    var scores = GetScores();
    IList<Score> externalScores = new List<Score>();

    var filteredScores = scores.Where(score => externalScores.All(x => x.RelationId != score.RelationId));

    foreach (var score in filteredScores)
    {
        externalScores.Add(score);
    }

    return externalScores.Count();
}
```

But when I add `.ToList()` to `filteredScores` (either in the foreach loop or after the linq operation) the result of the function is **3**.

I suspect it has something to do with [Closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Your code currently has `ToList()` in it already; I assume you forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `ToList`, all items in `scores` are checked if they match the predicate, which returns always true because `externalScores`  is empty.

Without `ToList`, each item in `scores` is checked interleaved with the `foreach` loop (see: [*Deferred Execution*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)) which modifies `externalScores`, causing the predicate to return `true` for the first item and `false` for the other two items.

Comment: I was trying to figure out _why_ `filteredScores` returned empty after `externalScores` had an item added - I'd totally missed that all the `RelationId` properties return _the same GUID_.

Comment: Brilliant, never thought of that.